# Encontrar vírgula nos parâmetros de uma função usando regex

Tags: java, regex

Preciso encontrar a ocorrência de uma chamada de funções em cadeia, mas preciso incluir o caso em que haja mais de um parâmetro passado, como:

```
Tower.getType(i,j).initialPrice(f,g);
```

Até agora só consegui formular o regex de quando há apenas um parâmetro:

```
[\\w]+([\\.]+[\\w]+[(]+[\\w]*+[)]){2,}+[;]
```

O trecho do código:

```
public static void verificaMessageChain (String s) {        
    if (s!=null && s.matches("[\\w]+([\\.]+[\\w]+[(]+[\\w]*+[)]){2,}+[;]")) {
        System.out.println("\nÉ Message Chain para "+s+"\n");
        splitMessageChain(s); // {0,} equivale a *
    } else if (s!=null && s.matches("[\\w] + ([\\.] + [\\w] + [(] + [\\w]* + ([\\,] + [\\w])* + [)]) {2,} + [;]")) {
        System.out.println("\nÉ Message Chain para "+s+"\n");
        splitMessageChain(s);
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nNão é Message Chain para "+s+"\n");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Observe a expressão `metodo(a.b(c, (d + e.f(g, h(i) + j, k) * m), n.o(p, q, r.s().t(u.v())), w), x, y + z)` - A conclusão é que para lidar com ela corretamente você precisaria de uma linguagem livre-de-contexto, e não regular.

Comment: Mas e para uma simples? Como metodo(a, b, c), não preciso conseguir analisar todos os casos, mas alguns simples pelo menos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este seu caso você pode usar a seguinte REGEX :

```
[a-z]\((([a-z]+,?)*)\)
```

[Veja no REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/tC2yL8/1)

#### Explicação

A logica usada foi que um método teria o padrão **LETRAS**(**PARAMETROS**), entende que letras pode ser uma letra (`a(params)`), e mesmo que seja mais de um letra (`minhaFuncao(params)`), note que segue o padrão de uma letra tambem (`o(params)`).
Com isso em mente :

- `[a-z]\(` - define que deve ter uma letra seguida de `(`.
- `(([a-z]+,?)*)` - grupo 1 que vai buscar os parâmetros.
- `([a-z]+,?)*` - os parâmetros seriam letras/palavras, separados por virgula, podendo ter infinitos ou nenhum `*`.
- `\)` - deve terminal com `)`.

#### Nota

Esta REGEX serve para seu caso especifico, se os parâmetros forem variáveis, caso sejam sentenças como o [@Victor disse no comentario](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149120/encontrar-v%C3%ADrgula-nos-par%C3%A2metros-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usando-regex#comment307987_149120), você não vai conseguir usá-la, mesmo o parametro sendo uma string `"texto"`.

#### Adendo

Se quiser que pegue tanto `[A-Za-z]` coloque a flag `i` ou altere as sentenças `[a-z]` para o mesmo.